# RabbitMQ bad_ssl_dist_optfile

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, rabbitmq

so I'm working on getting RabbitMQ up in a clustered setting, and I "think" I have the configuration to have the cluster nodes talk to each other over SSL, but when running the nodes, I get this error:

```
rmq-node-1         |               {{shutdown,
rmq-node-1         |                    {failed_to_start_child,ssl_dist_sup,
rmq-node-1         |                        {'EXIT',
rmq-node-1         |                            {{bad_ssl_dist_optfile,
rmq-node-1         | 16:36:58.591 [error]                    {failed_to_start_child,ssl_dist_sup,
rmq-node-1         | 16:36:58.592 [error]                        {'EXIT',
rmq-node-1         | 16:36:58.592 [error]                            {{bad_ssl_dist_optfile,
rmq-node-1         |                                 ["/etc/rabbitmq/inter_node_tls.config"]},
rmq-node-1         |                             [{ssl_dist_sup,consult,1,
rmq-node-1         |                                  [{file,"ssl_dist_sup.erl"},{line,105}]},
rmq-node-1         | 16:36:58.593 [error]                                 ["/etc/rabbitmq/inter_node_tls.config"]},
rmq-node-1         |                              {ssl_dist_sup,start_link,0,
rmq-node-1         |                                  [{file,"ssl_dist_sup.erl"},{line,45}]},
```

The gist of the error is the line that says `bad_ssl_dist_optfile` and I'm thinking the configuration is part of the problem. I've been following this guide: [Securing Cluster Communications - Option 2 - config files](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering-ssl.html#linux-strategy-two)

I also generated the `pem` files with the recommended "easy" solution. (also did the same with `easy-rsa` and got the same issues.) [automated certificate generation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#automated-certificate-generation)

I've setup my folder structure like so:
[image: Folder Structure]

I've created a compose file to include all the files, variables, and configuration:
[image: Compose File]

I've created a `rabbitmq.conf`, `rabbitmq-env.conf`, and `inter_node_tls.config` to complete the setup:
*RabbitMQ Config*
[image: RabbitMQ config file]
*RabbitMQ Env*
[image: RabbitMQ Env File]
*Inter Node SSL*
[image: Inter Node SSL Options]

Am I missing a piece of the configuration? or is there some issue with formatting on the inter node configuration?

EDIT: I did catch the file name issue with the TLS config file, but got the same issue.